# How can I decrease the value of a field of a queryset simultaneously?

Tags: django, rest

I want to make a site where people can make listings for things to sell. I want it to have a front page where the most popular (hot) items are always displayed.
Popularity decreases with time and increases with activity (bidding, commenting, clicking). Every item starts with a popularity of 100.
That way uninteresting items dissapear quickly and interesting ones stay on longer.
So everytime a user interacts with the objects its popularity should increase (for example, everytime a get request from a unique user is made for the details of the object, its popularity value goes up by 1, every bid increases it by 10).
On the opposite, everytime a minute or so passes, the popularity of all currently active items decreases. Once it hits 0, it will be "deactivated" it will still be tradable, but it will never hit the frontpage again.
The problem is, how do I decrease the popularity of a queryset of all active items?
I realize that everytime the user request the front page. I could just fetch all active objects, calculate the popularity within python code and sort them by hand, but that seams rather wastefull.
I know I can easily set a property of an entire queryset, by using the update function, but that only takes one absolute value for the entire set. Is there a built in way to just decrease the property by one?
Or do I just have to loop through the queryset and decrease every value manually?

Comment: Just a comment - 100 minutes are less than 2 hours - so if anybody put sell late evening, it would be "deactivated" before it have even chance to be shown - also there is a lot of time zones and not everyone has day at the same time, therefore distant users would post at strange hours.

Comment: Yeah the numbers are nonsense. It was mostly just to visualize the problem. The finetuning comes later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Item(models.Model):
    popularity = models.IntegerField()

Item.objects.update(popularity=models.F('popularity')-1)
```

This is how you update a queryset based on the values it has instead of giving it an absolute value, you can tweak this around to fit your needs.

Comment: This instruction is fully database atomic, right? Just for concurrencies sake

Comment: Yes django, by default, uses `transaction.atomic()` context decorator in the update method. All django ORM functions are by default atomic as far as I'm aware.